# How to force textual merging with p4merge?

Tags: linux, merge, diff, perforce, p4merge

I'm using Perforce and its default merge tool p4merge. On integration I have several conflicts in a `vcproj` I wish to resolve.

But it seems p4merge tries to somehow interpret the file's contents and only says "Image files can not be merged" then exits. This way I cannot resolve the conflict and cannot even get get a diff.

It's either a very new unreported bug, or have a very trivial workaround, because Google search shows absolutely nothing related about it (except a Twitter post).

Does anybody knows a workaround?

(I'm using the Linux version of Perforce.)

UPDATE:

The Perforce file type is 'text'. So they are not binary.

Comment: Your search results probably don't turn up much because most people probably check in `.vcproj` files as text files instead of as binary files.  You can change a file's type by doing `p4 edit -t text FILE` and resubmitting it.

Comment: James is probably right. In order to check the filetypes call "p4 filelog FILE" on all involved files (source & target). They should be "text" (or something including "text").

Comment: They ARE text... 

The results probably don't turn up much because no one use Perforce on Linux...

Comment: Google for your error message and you'll find a tweet where somebody has the same problem and suggests falling back to an older version of p4merge.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on P4V for mac (version "MACOSX105X86_64/2012.1/475402"). Whenever I try to diff/merge files with uncommon extensions (in my case I'm working on files that end in .mxml and .actionScriptProperties), it complains about how they are image files. I can confirm that they are in the repo as <text> files. I think it must be a new issue. And I can't even find a workaround, I wish there was a way to disable image-file support altogether.

Comment: I reported a Perforce bug but they refused to deal with it, because the support time for our p4 server is elapsed...

Anyway this bug has nothing to do with p4 server because it happens if you use p4merge without Perforce.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error too (using tools that say "2012 June 06" in the about box). I just downloaded the latest tools from the Perforce website (dated "2012 December 17"), and the bug went away. Try downloading the latest tools!